# SQL Server 2008 Complex Query & Table Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is a little difficult to explain but I will try my best. I have a database which maintains information on Marine Shipping etc. I have the following columns to work with. (There are others but they don't have any purpose for my study) I have Message_ID, Latitude, Longitude, MMSI (This represents individual ship signals, hence they are unique to ships) Ship_type, Vessel_name.

So here's the issue

- I need only Message_ID's 1 and 3.
- Unfortunately Message_ID's 1 and 3 have Ship_type and Vessel_name as Null within their  respective spots.
- Message_ID 5 has both Ship_type and Vessel_name marked.
- My study area is within given latitude and longitudes

Essentially what I need to do is append the Ship_type and Vessel_name to the lines with Message_ID's 1 and 3 by way of joining through the MMSI number which is shared by a Message_ID 5.

the queries I have so far..

```
WHERE (latitude > 55 and latitude < 85 and longitude > 50 and longitude < 141) And (Message_ID = 1 or Message_ID = 3);
```

Other Query

```
WHERE Message_ID = 5;
```

How do I join all Ship_type and Vessel_name that result in the second query to the first query?

I FEEL LIKE IT SHOULD BE MENTIONED THAT EVERYTHING IS WITHIN ONE TABLE ENTITLED dbo.DecodedCSVMEssages_Staging THAT HAS ABOUT 100 MILLION ENTRIES.. :S

Answer (score 2):

I would probably do it like this:

```
SELECT
     t13.Message_ID, 
     t13.Latitude, 
     t13.Longitude, 
     t13.MMSI,
     t5.Ship_type, 
     t5.Vessel_name
FROM yourTable As t13
OUTER APPLY (   SELECT TOP 1 * 
                FROM  yourTable As t5
                WHERE t5.Message_ID = 5
                  AND t5.MMSI = t13.MMSI
             ) As t5
WHERE t13.Message_ID IN(1,3)
  AND t13.latitude > 55 
  and t13.latitude < 85 
  and t13.longitude > 50 
  and t13.longitude < 141
```

Comment: what does t13. and t5. stand for?

Comment: @dpalm that's convenient syntax called a [table alias](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455.aspx).

Comment: so essentially you've given the table name an alias?

Comment: Yes, it's the same as `SELECT yourTable.Message_ID, [...]` but could be less typing, and more importantly allows a subquery to unambiguously reference a table in the outer query (in this case in the `OUTER APPLY` portion).

Comment: @dpalm Yes.  They're a convenience when you have long table names that you don't want to clutter up the column names.  However, they're required for subqueries (and CTEs) and when you reference the same table/view more than once in the same `FROM` clause, so that the SQL compiler can tell which table+column you are referring to in your column references.

Comment: how come you decided to leave out the longitude and latitude specifications?

Comment: @dpalm Yikes! I forgot about them. .. Fixed now.

Comment: It says ambiguous column name latitude and the same for longitude

Comment: @dpalm Stupid me, after yammering on and on about the aliases, I forgot to add them to this part... :-(  ... Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

```
with ship_cte(Ship_type,Vessel_name,MMSI)
as(select Distinct Ship_type,Vessel_name,MMSI  from TableName WHERE Message_ID = 5)

select b.Ship_type,b.Vessel_name,a.other_columns 
from tableName a join ship_cte b on a.MMSI=b.MMSI
WHERE (a.latitude > 55 and a.latitude < 85 and a.longitude > 50 and a.longitude < 141) 
And (a.Message_ID = 1 or a.Message_ID = 3);
```

Here in the first part of the query I'm getting ship_type and vessel_name for all the rows where message_id=5, and then I'm joining this part of the query with main table on the basis of MMSI number.

Comment: You are going to get multiplications on your Join unless the table is unique on `(MMSI, Message_ID)`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it @RBarryYoung, I've edited the code to consider only distinct.

Comment: Good point, I assumed (Message_ID,MMSI) was unique in my answer as well.  The `TOP(1)` addresses it in any case.

Comment: I'm relatively new to SQL Server, I'm not sure where the ship_cte came from?

Comment: @dpalm: Its called CTE, I've declared it in the first part, kindly run the whole query replacing tablename or column name as required, this would help you more in understanding the concept.

Comment: what is a.other_columns ? (getting closer though!)

Comment: @dpalm The `with` clause defines CTEs (Common Table Expressions) which are just a type of subquery. `ship_cte` is it's alias because table subqueries must have an alias so that you can refer to their columns later on.

Comment: I've used other_columns here, as I'm not aware of the other column names you want to fetch from your table, so you can replace your column name with other_columns

Comment: well it's currently running! fingers crossed.. It should take a long time.. there are about 100 million rows of data

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
select Message_ID, Latitude, Longitude, MMSI, x.Ship_type, x.Vessel_name
from table t
outer apply (select Ship_type, Vessel_name from table x where x.MMSI=t.MMSI and x.Message_ID=5) x
where t.Message_ID in (1,3) and (latitude > 55 and latitude < 85 and longitude > 50 and longitude < 141);
```

Comment: what does the x stand for?

Comment: It is the alias given to the `OUTER APPLY` part in the query.